# How to deploy a Koa based TypeScript project into both AWS Lambda and Azure Cloud Function?

Tags: typescript, azure, aws-lambda, koa, serverless

I got a web application which developed using Koa.JS. I want to deploy to both Azure Cloud Function and AWS Lambda. so I don't need to maintenance the server stuffs and also I don't locked in with the cloud vendor.

Any framework can support this kind of requirements?

This is the web application I got.

index.ts

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

app.use(async ctx => {
    ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any framework can support this kind of requirements?

Express (the older Koa) is more widely supported

- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express
- https://github.com/yvele/azure-function-express

## More

Cloud vendors have various associated services (e.g. hosted databases) that differ significantly. You are going to struggle to get complete cloud redundancy. You will be best served using the internal redundancy options in the cloud provider you choose.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. Unfortunately we don't use express at all.

Comment: @giLisH I am developing a platform independent framework to deploy to serverless vendors(Lambda, Azure, Google, Alibabacloud), you can find the example here https://github.com/agentframework/web-starter

Answer (score 0):

Seems the typescript support is still in process, but here is a package that does what you're seeking: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-serverless-koa

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but for anyone still looking for something that fits these requirements, [Curveball](https://github.com/curveball/core) is a framework that fits the criteria well. I haven't used it but it definitely seems like something that's worth checking out!

Edit: For anyone interested they also have support for Bun and Node.